# jquery: .data('x', 'y') vs .attr('data-x', 'y')

Tags: jquery

I have just discovered that If I set data attribute using `.data()` I can't search the element using jquery attribute selector but If I set it using `.attr()`, searching works.

Output from my chrome console:

```
$('body').append($('<div></div>').data('x', 'y'));
[<body>​…​</body>​]
$('div[data-x="y"]')
[]
$('body').append($('<div></div>').attr('data-x', 'y'));
[<body>​…​</body>​]
$('div[data-x="y"]')
[<div data-x=​"y">​</div>​]
```

My question is if it save to assume it will work correctly in every browser If I use .attr().

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Data vs Attr?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work correctly, however you should be using `data()` as a getter and a setter.

The reason for this is because jQuery stores all `data-*` attributes in an object which it maintains in memory. This means it is *much* faster than accessing the DOM each time to read/write an attribute.

If you need to select an element by a data attribute, use `filter()` - it will most likely still be faster than an attribute selector, although I've not tested.

```
var $filteredElements = $('.lots-of-elements').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('foo') == 'bar';
});
```

Comment: That was fast. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't select/search for `.data()` values on the page because they are stored in memory internally by jQuery.

`jQuery.data('element','x','y');` is like `elements['element']['x'] = 'y';` for some variable in jQuery's memory

whereas

`$('element').attr('data-x','y')` yields `<element data-x="y">` on the page.

As for your question, it's answered in the jQuery documentation:

> Using jQuery's .attr() method to get the value of an element's attribute has two main
>   benefits:
>
> - Convenience: It can be called directly on a jQuery object and chained
>     to other jQuery methods.
> - **Cross-browser consistency: The values of some
>     attributes are reported inconsistently across browsers, and even
>     across versions of a single browser. The .attr() method reduces such
>     inconsistencies.**

http://api.jquery.com/attr/